# Ubuntu equivalent command to Windows tasklist command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash

I have a couple lines in PHP to check if a specific process is currently running on my server. If the process is running, I include a script that is used in to interact with said process. Below is the code

```
ob_start(NULL, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);
system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq websocket.exe" /FO TABLE /NH');
$return = ob_get_clean();
if (!($return === false || stripos($return, 'websocket') === false)) {
    $hData['Script'][] =    'websocket.js';
}//END IF
```

Currently the system call is only usable in Windows because `tasklist` is a Windows specific command. Since I am still learning Ubuntu and Unix I cannot think of a way to get a similar output to my Windows command. I've thought about using `ps` to check for my process but I don't know how to refine the results based on process name.

Is there a command in Ubuntu that is similar to my Windows command `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq websocket.exe" /FO TABLE /NH` that will allow me to filter out non matching processes? The goal is to make it efficient for both Ubuntu and PHP. So filtering the results as much as possible is recommended

*Extra Information*

I am planning on using this to check if my websocket server is running and if it is include the script so users can use it.

I tried doing `ps -ef | grep -i "websocket"` but it would return `grep --color=auto -i websocket` which would match the criteria for PHP and include the script. I would like to try to avoid that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe the results to `grep -v grep` like `ps -ef | grep -i "websocket" | grep -v grep` This will remove the ps record with the grep in it.

Comment: Would you say that this option is as efficient as the Windows `tasklist` with filtering that I provided in the question?

Comment: I think you will find it to be very fast and efficient.

Comment: Also, I'm totally down with NuTTyX's answer too. Often in Linux there are many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: As you replied first and my answer was almost the same, I'm including as a comment to yours: Since grep starts a new command while listing and have the same search term that it should find, it finds itself and other commands. I recommend to modify your grep to surround any single letter between brackets `[]`: `ps -ef | grep -i "[w]ebsocket" `

Comment: This worked great. I don't notice a performance hit. Thanks